# ajax page navigation not working after htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i use .htaccess to rewrite my url from

```
/list.php?pat=free&mainCol=maincate&subCol=shoes
```

to

/maincate/shoes

after rewrite, the ajax next page button is not working anymore. it should load list_pull.php from same folder as list.php

```
    $.post("list_pull.php",{
        pageCurrent:pageClick,      
        pullSubCol:$("#pullSubCol").val()});
```

and the htaccess is like this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ /list.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1&subCol=$2  [L]
```

i tried use full path http://www.mydomain.com/list_pull.php - not working
i tried creating a folder "maincate" and put listpull.php inside, still not working.

by the way, i have another file same as listpull.php, and it works!
the rewrite is like this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /mainlist.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1  [L]
```

dont know if my question is clear enough, been trying to figure it out for 2 days now, still no luck.

thanks in advance for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have redirected all the params after domain name  to `mainlist.php` and the uri string with two `/` to `list.php` so i suggest you to add another specific rewrite rule for `list_pull.php` and replace **[L]** with **[QSA]**

`QSA` means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite (`olle?p=1` will be rewritten as `index.php?url=olle&p=1`.

`L` means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.

```
RewriteRule ^call_ajax$ /list_pull.php  [QSA]
```

Now in your ajax call put url like this

```
$.post("/call_ajax",{
        pageCurrent:pageClick,      
        pullSubCol:$("#pullSubCol").val()
});
```

**Edit** Try [**htaccess.madewithlove.be**](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to test your rewrite rules below i have attached some test rewrites which works fine for me

**1) http://www.example.com/call_ajax** to **RewriteRule ^call_ajax$ /list_pull.php  [QSA]**

[image]

**2) http://www.example.com/call/ajax to RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ /list.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1&subCol=$2  [QSA]**

[image]

**3) http://www.example.com/call to RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /mainlist.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1  [QSA]**

[image]

Comment: i even comment out :RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /mainlist.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1  [L] " seems like it won't work with two / in the url

Comment: is there anyway i can rewrite the list.php url to something with only one slash?? RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ /list.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1&subCol=$2  [QSA], something like ^([^/.]+)-([^/.]+)$, then it wont confuse with the ajax post

Comment: @will.i.am yes you can then your url will look like test-test =([^/.]+)-([^/.]+) have you tried this http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: it works if i comment out mainlist.php, is there anyway for them to share same directory but wont interfere the other??
^([^/.]+)$ /mainlist.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1  [QSA]
^([^/.]+)-([^/.]+)$ /list.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1&subCol=$2  [QSA]

Comment: RewriteRule ^123([^/.]+)$ /mainlist.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)-([^/.]+)$ /list.php?pat=free&mainCol=$1&subCol=$2  [QSA]

this works for me now, i have to add something before mainlist.php in the htaccess. the 123 will do the job, thanks for your help.

Comment: @will.i.am in above case your urls that starts with 123 will redirect to mainlist.php so in short if you want to redirect the urls to mainlist.php then they should start with 123 otherwise they will not redirect to mainlist.php

Answer (score 0):

Just add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before RewriteRule