# More than one rewriterule

Tags: php, regex, apache

The idea is to get different variables depending of which **php** file I'm including, so I avoid too much confusion when programming.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)$ index.php?p=$1&produccion=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)$ index.php?p=$1&categoria=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)$ index.php?p=$1&categoria=$2&show=$3 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thing is, when I leave it like this, it will overwrite the previous `RewriteRule`.

I'm really new to this regex and apache thing.

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814239/ajax-page-navigation-not-working-after-htaccess-rewrite/18814351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using **just one RewriteRule:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And then parsing the `$_GET['p']` variable in PHP to determine the appropriate page:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? explode('/', $_GET['p']) : null;
if ($page) {
    if ($page[0] == 'store') {
        if ($page[1] == 'cart') {
            // URL is www.example.com/store/cart
        }
        else if (!isset($page[1]) || empty($page[1])) {
            // URL is www.example.com/store
        }
    }
}
else {
    // URL is www.example.com
}
```

This isn't exactly ideal for your site's infrastructure. You also might consider being more specific with your RewriteRules if you don't want absolutely everything to be redirected. Take this for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(about|faq|signup|contact)(?!\.php)/?(.*)$ /$1.php?page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The above rule will only redirect when a user visits `example.com/about`, or `/faq`, or `/signup`, or `/contact`, and they'll be redirected to a PHP file of the same name. For example, requests to `/faq/3` will redirect to `/faq.php?page=3`.

Comment: This `RewriteRule`, it is meant to be used **always** once?

Comment: Yes. So if someone goes to www.example.com/store/cart, then they'll be redirected to /index.php?p=store/cart. Then, `$page[0]` will be set to `store` and `$page[1]` will be set to `cart`.